# Why is aluminium used to treat waste after a lab experiment?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, safety

How does adding aluminum metal pieces into a waste beaker help treat solids and liquids in the beaker so you can safely send the solids to a landfill and dispose of the liquids in the sink drain following a lab experiment?

Comment: Not clear where you are, but I know that I absolutely cannot dispose of anything down the sink, regardless of whether I have 'treated' it or not. That would be a great way to get the city and state to shut me down.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably because aluminium is a very reactive metal and reacts with acids **and** bases both to form less reactive compounds. (Amphoteric Nature)

1. With acids
   $$\ce{Al + HCl -> AlCl3 + H2}$$
2. With Bases
   $$\ce{Al + NaOH + H2O -> NaAl(OH)4 + H2}$$

Comment: Sodium aluminate is really $\ce{NaAl(OH)4}$.

Comment: Ok will correct,( it's given like that in my textbook)

Comment: That's a very old notation that does not represent the true structure of the aluminate ion.